# convert csv file to nested nested list of dictionaries using python

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv file to nested json: I'm looking for json output something like this.

here is my json data:

```
[
   {
      "RID":"test",
      "UId":"userl@gmail.com",
      "Ugroup":"abc",
      "Query":[
         {
            "Status":"query1",
            "ECategory":"error1"
         },
         {
            "Status":"query2",
            "ECategory":"error2"
         }
      ],
      "SuccesfulQ":"7",
      "FailedQ":"0"
   },
   {
      "RID":"test2",
      "Uld":"user2@gmail.com",
      "Ugroup":"xyz",
      "Query":[
         {
            "Statement":"query3",
            "ECategory":"error3"
         },
         {
            "Statement":"query4",
            "ECategory":"error4"
         }
      ],
      "SuccesfulQ":"7",
      "FailedQ":"0"
   }
]
```

Here is my CSV file

[csvfile][2]

```
    RID,UId,Ugroup,Query.Statement,Query.ECategory,SuccesfulQ,FailedQ
   test,user1@gmail.com,abc,query1,error1,            7,        0
   test,user1@gmail.com,abc,query2,error2             7,        0
   test2,user2@gmail.com,xyz,query3,error3            7,        0
   test2,user2@gmail.com,xyz,query4,error4            7,        0
```

using below code i'm getting normal json not a nested one:

```
import csv
import json
def make_json(csvFilePath):
    data = {}
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        a = [{k:v for k,v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(csvf, skipinitialspace=True)]
        print(a)
csvFilePath = r'table.csv'
make_json(csvFilePath)
```

Comment: Please include code and data as txt not images, see guidelines

Comment: Is there always one extra row of data (2 rows per user) or can there be multiple rows?

Comment: thanks for your response @Mike67. SQLQuery.Status and SQLQuery.ECategory are the nested columns. only these two column will have one extra value. for more information please click on json file  to see the json schema link above.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, after you create list of dictionaries, you can just iterate over the odd rows and append the data from the even rows. After that, you can use `json.dumps` to convert the full list to json.

Try this code. It assumes 2 rows per user query:

```
cs = '''
RID,UId,Ugroup,Statement,ECategory,SuccesfulQ,FailedQ
test1,user1@gmail.com,abc,query1,error1,7,0
test1,user1@gmail.com,abc,query2,error2,7,0
test2,user2@gmail.com,xyz,query3,error3,7,0
test2,user2@gmail.com,xyz,query4,error4,7,0
'''.strip()

with open('table.csv','w') as f: f.write(cs)  # write test file

############# Main Script ##############

import csv
import json

def make_json(csvFilePath):
    data = {}
    lst = []    
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        a = [{k:v for k,v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(csvf, skipinitialspace=True)]
        for i in range(0,len(a),2):  # odd rows
           a[i]['Query'] = [  # combined data, new column
           {'Statement':a[i]['Statement'],'ECategory':a[i]['ECategory']},
           {'Statement':a[i+1]['Statement'],'ECategory':a[i+1]['ECategory']}
           ]           
           del a[i]['Statement'] # remove old columns
           del a[i]['ECategory']
           lst.append(a[i])  # final list  # odd rows only
        return json.dumps(lst)
        
csvFilePath = r'table.csv'
jsnFilePath = r'table.json'
jsn = make_json(csvFilePath)

with open (jsnFilePath,'w') as f:
   f.write(jsn)
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "RID": "test1",
        "UId": "user1@gmail.com",
        "Ugroup": "abc",
        "SuccesfulQ": "7",
        "FailedQ": "0",
        "Query": [
            {
                "Statement": "query1",
                "ECategory": "error1"
            },
            {
                "Statement": "query2",
                "ECategory": "error2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "RID": "test2",
        "UId": "user2@gmail.com",
        "Ugroup": "xyz",
        "SuccesfulQ": "7",
        "FailedQ": "0",
        "Query": [
            {
                "Statement": "query3",
                "ECategory": "error3"
            },
            {
                "Statement": "query4",
                "ECategory": "error4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```